# How to draw the classic state diagram using Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, drawing, state-diagram

Is it possible and practical for Mathematica to draw something like this (being created by Graphviz):

[image]

This is the best that I can get (but the shape and style are not satisfying):

[image]

Code:

```
GraphPlot[{{A -> C, "go"}, {C -> B, "gone"}, {C -> D, 
   "went"}, {C -> C, "loop"}}, VertexLabeling -> True, 
 DirectedEdges -> True]
```

Comment: There is no reason you cannot use graphics primitives to draw something like this.  Are you requesting an automatic layout solution?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, I am looking for some higher level primitives for drawing complicated state diagrams. I don't know whether Mathematica provides that. I searched through the documentation and checked the options of "GraphPlot" function and ended up with the code above.

Comment: Why did you accept my answer?  The shape it still wrong.  I appreciate it, but I think you should wait for a better answer.

Comment: Yes, I think it may inhibit other answers.  Again, thank you however.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You are a very nice person to have in a community, thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do something like this using `VertexRenderingFunction`.

```
GraphPlot[{{A -> C, "go"}, {C -> B, "gone"}, {C -> D, "went"}, {C -> C, "loop"}}, 
 DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({{White, Disk[#, 0.15]}, 
     AbsoluteThickness[2], Circle[#, 0.15], 
     If[MatchQ[#2, A | B], Circle[#, 0.12], {}], Text[#2, #]} &)]
```

[image]

---

*Method Updated February 2015*

To preserve the ability to interactively rearrange the graph with the drawing tools (double click) one must keep the vertex graphics inside of `GraphicsComplex`, with indexes rather than coordinates.  I believe one could do this from `VertexRenderingFunction` using an incrementing variable but it seems easier an possibly more robust to do it with post-processing.  This works in versions 7 and 10 of *Mathematica*, presumably 8 and 9 as well:

```
GraphPlot[
  {{A -> C, "go"}, {C -> B, "gone"}, {C -> D, "went"}, {C -> C, "loop"}},
  DirectedEdges -> True
] /.
 Tooltip[Point[n_Integer], label_] :>
   {{White, Disk[n, 0.15]},
    Black, AbsoluteThickness[2], Circle[n, 0.15], 
    If[MatchQ[label, A | B], Circle[n, 0.12], {}], Text[label, n]}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a "VertexLabelingFunction"?

Comment: @Ning I had an error in my answer; I meant `VertexRenderingFunction`.  I don't believe there is a Vertex**Labeling*Funcion.  Also, I noticed that I had a flaw in my graphics relative to your original example regarding the circle sizes.  I corrected this is the second version I just put up.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need for interactive placement to get your vertices at the desired location as mr.Wizard suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109374/how-to-draw-the-classic-state-diagram-using-mathematica/8109449#8109449). You can use `VertexCoordinateRules` for that:

```
GraphPlot[{{A -> C, "go"}, {C -> B, "gone"}, {C -> D, "went"}, {C -> C, "loop"}}, 
    DirectedEdges -> True, 
    VertexRenderingFunction -> 
          ({{White, Disk[#, 0.15]}, AbsoluteThickness[2], Circle[#, 0.15], 
           If[MatchQ[#2, A | B], Circle[#, 0.12], {}], Text[#2, #]} &),
    VertexCoordinateRules -> 
          {A -> {0, 0}, C -> {0.75, 0},B -> {1.5, 0.25}, D -> {1.5, -0.25}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't mean that it was necessary to have interactive layout, but I can see how that may be inferred.  This method works too.  Do you know of any way to preserve the editability besides a variation of the hack I used?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't see an easy way out.